# Getting this Error **"ERROR: Failed to resolve: :sinch-android-rtc:+"**

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I want to make calls using my application I want to integrate sinch into my application

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation(name:'sinch-android-rtc', version:'+', ext:'aar')
}
```

Added This too

```
flatDir {
            dirs '/libs'
        }
```

Also added into lib

[into my lib folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX5xH.png)

Answer (score 0):

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(name:'sinch-android-rtc', version:'+', ext:'aar')
}

its aar files now days, where did you see the jar?

Comment: i didn't get it what are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

allprojects {

```
repositories {

    google()

    jcenter()

    flatDir {

        dirs 'libs'

    }

}
```

}

Please add like this in build.gradle